Why am I able to save a PySpark dataframe with different casing at a nested level?
I am experiencing unexpected behaviour when saving Dataframes where the casing varies at a nested level. I am loading data from a JSON file into a PySpark Dataframe, saving it in delta format, and then repeating with different casing.
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def test_weird_casing_behaviour(
    spark,
):
    location = "some_location"
    first_snapshot_df = spark.read.json(
        "./first_snapshot.json"
    )
    first_snapshot_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option(
        "overwriteSchema", "true"
    ).save(location)

    delta_df = spark.read.json(
        "./delta.json"
    )
    delta_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("mergeSchema", "true").save(
        location
    )

    staging_df_at_start = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, location).toDF()
    print("target table length post merge", staging_df_at_start.count())

    null_filter_condition = F.col("testing.myid").isNull()
    null_statement_ids = staging_df_at_start.filter(null_filter_condition)
    non_null_statement_ids = staging_df_at_start.filter(~null_filter_condition)
    print("null_statement_ids", null_statement_ids.count())
    print("non_null_statement_ids", non_null_statement_ids.count())

The content of the first_snapshot JSON file is:
[
    {
        "testing": {
            "myid": "id10"
        }, 
        "_someotherrootfield": {
            "myfield": "dddd"
        }
    }
]

The content of the delta JSON file is:
[
    {
        "testing": {
            "myId": "id1"
        }, 
        "_someOtherRootField": {
            "myfield": "dddd"
        }
    }
]

So the only difference is the casing of the nested myid. When saving these 2, it does NOT fail when saving. But when I filter for the null and non-null rows based on the column testing.myid, only 1 of the rows gets captured.
Weirdly, if I were to remove the _someOtherRootField from both of the JSON files, then it would FAIL to save the delta file and complain that Nested fields need renaming to avoid data loss. It REQUIRES for there to be a casing difference at a root field level between the 2 JSON files to enable the nested casing difference to save successfully (yet it still seems to have issues once filtering on the nested column with casing differences). Is this expected behaviour?
I am using version 3.4.1 of Pyspark.

Seems like a bug. You should open an issue if it is not present already.
